# Reading Characters from a Word ? Java

Tags: java, character, bufferedreader

I am trying to get the characters or the letters from a word.

For example:

```
input = "apple"
output = "a", "p", "p", "l", "e"
```

However, I am using the `BufferedReader` class.
Is there any way to read characters using `BufferedReader`?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String input = "apple";
char[] arr = input.toCharArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Output:

```
[a, p, p, l, e]
```

Comment: Using System.out.println(arr); should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

The `read()` method of `BufferedReader` gives you a single character.

Have a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a `char[]` into the `read` method.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be just converting the input to an char array.. Your buffered reader reads a line, split it to words with `.split("delim")` then convert each of the words.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `read()` in `BufferedReader` class or use `toCharArray()` method . Both can be used.

```
String input="Apple";
BufferedReader br=BufferedReader.read(input);

or
char in=input.toCharArray();
```